# Surface of the top of a sphere

Tags: integration, surface-integrals

For $0<h<r$ there is a surface
$$C=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2, z\geq h\}$$

I know that area$=\int\int_C1dS=\int\int_D|R_u\times R_v|dA$, where $R$ is my parametrization and $D$ the domain of parametrization.

Is $R(\phi,\theta)=(h\sin\phi\cos\theta,h\sin\phi\sin\theta,h\cos\phi)$ a good parametrization? And if so, what are the boundaries of $\phi$ and $\theta$?

Edit:Or should I use spherical coordinates (and again what would the boundaries be in that case?)

Comment: You're already using spherical coordinates, except as written the radius is $h$ instead of $r$. :) (Also, your area integral contains a spurious factor of $R(u, v)$.) The longitude $\theta$ runs over one full turn, and the co-latitude $\phi$ runs over the interval required to make $z \geq h$. Before worrying about that, however, calculate $|R_{\theta} \times R_{\phi}|$; it may turn out that you can evaluate the area integral easily without knowing the bounds on $\phi$. (Wink, wink.)

Comment: @user86418 wouldnt that be $|R_\theta\times R\phi|=h^2\sin\phi$?

Comment: Yes...well, $r^{2}\sin\phi$; so the area integrand is $r^{2} \sin\phi\, d\theta\, d\phi$, which happens to be $-r\, d\theta\, dz$. :) The sign goes away because integrating from $\phi = 0$ to $\phi = \phi_{0}$ amounts to integrating from $z = r$ to $z = h$.

Comment: @user86418 i don't really get that, could you maybe show me the computation?

Comment: Why is $r^2\sin\phi d\theta d\phi=-rd\theta dz$?

Comment: Since $z = r\cos\phi$ (N.B. $r$, not $h$) and $r$ is constant, $dz = -r\sin\phi\, d\phi$. :)

Comment: @user86418 and what would the final answer be then? Is it $-2\pi r(r-h)$?

Comment: Yes (except for the sign). :) (This is a famous theorem of Archimedes; the area of a "zone" on a sphere is equal to the area of a zone of equal height on a circumscribed cylinder, namely $2\pi r$ times the height.)

Comment: @user86418 can you look at the answer i posted below?

Answer (score 1):

We use spherical coordinates, then the area $A$ is
$$A=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_\phi r^2\sin\phi d\phi d\theta=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{z=r}^h -rd\theta dz=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{z=h}^r rd\theta dz=2\pi r(r-h).$$

Comment: Looks good.... :)

Comment: @user86418 Thank you for all your help! :)